# Add Search filter on table in angular 5

Tags: angular, html-table, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using angular 5 typescript. I want to add search filter in my table. I am retrieving collection of activities from Firestore as:

```
 this.activities = this.afs.collection('activities').valueChanges();
```

and show there fields in the form of boostrap table by using ngFor.

```
  <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Section</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Max Players</th>
           <th >Locked</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let activity of activities | async >

                   <td>
                     {{activity.section}}

                   </td>
                   <td >
                     {{activity.name}}
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   {{activity.maxPlayers}}
                 </td>

                   <td>
                     {{activity.locked}}
                   </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
```

Now I want to add filter search. How can I do this? I saw some tutorial on data filtering but they are applying on array, but I don't have any array for my collection activities.

Comment: I'm guessing that `activities` is an `Observable` that emits an array, is that right?

Comment: Maybe you could show us the code. As user18... guesses you're probably using an Observable.

Comment: Yes activities is observable. Yes i can share the code with you but how to share it?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a very simple to use library [ss-search](https://github.com/yann510/ss-search).

In your case, you would do the following:

```
search(await activities, ["section", "name", "maxPlayers", "locked"], "SEARCH_TERM")
```

This will filter out the data to return only results containing your search term.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, there are some points:

1. `</tbody>` is missing.
2. in *ngFor " is missing at the end.
3. ngFor only works for arrays and not objects, so this.activites has to be an array else it would give the same error.

Comment: Well, activities is being piped through `async`, so I'm guessing it's an `Observable`, not an array, although it's likely an `Observable` that emits an array.

Comment: there are many other things in the code, so i just copied that part for my question and paste it here. So there can be some code are missing. I define the activities as **activities: Observable<any[]>;**